# FirebirdSQL queries gets stuck at 12:00PM

Tags: sql, firebird, freeze

I'm running Firebird 2.5 (and have also tried earlier versions) on Windows. Every day after 12:00PM running insert/update queries on one specific table hang, but complete successfully by 12:35 or so, no matter when started. It does seem that Firebird is doing some kind of maintenance on the table and it takes half an hour to complete, during which time the table cannot be written to (but the reads are fast). The table itself is really small, some 10000 rows, compared to millions of rows we have in other tables - and other tables do not get stuck.

I haven't been able to find any reason or solution. I tried dumping the table and restoring it, which didn't help, I tried switching between superserver and classic, changed versions with no success.

Has anyone experienced a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Firebird doesn't have any internal maintenance procedures bind to some specified time of a day. Seems, there is some task on your server scheduled to run at 12:00 PM. Or there are network users of the server who start doing some heavy access at 12:00 PM.

Answer (score 0):

The only maintenance FB does is "garbage collection" (geting rid of old record versions) and this is done on "when needed" basis (usually when records were selected, see the `GCPolicy` in firebird.conf) not on some predefined time.

Do you experience this hang only on during these certain hours or is it always slow to insert to that table? Have you checked the server load during the slowdown (ie in the task manager, is the CPU maxed out)? Anyway, here is some ideas to check:

- What constraints / triggers do you have on the table? If they involve some extensive checks (ie against the other tables which contain millions of rows) this could be the reason inserts take so long.
- Perhaps there is some other service which is triggered at that time? Ie do you have a cron job to make backup of the DB at that time? Or perhaps some other system service which runs at that time with higher priority slows down the server?
- Do you have trace service active for the table? See fbtrace.conf in FireBird root directory. If it is active, extensive logging might be the cause of slowdown, if it isn't active, using it might help you to find the cause.
- What are the setings for `ForcedWrites` / `UnflushedWrites` (see firebird.conf)? Does changing them make difference?
- Is there something logged for this troublesome timeframe in firebird.log?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have a process which starts at 12:00 and does something which locks the entire table. Use the monitoring table or the trace manager to see if there is any connection or active transaction which looks suspicious.
I also think your own transaction are started with the WAIT clause without a LOCK TIMEOUT, you might want to change this to NO WAIT or WAIT with a LOCK TIMEOUT, so that your transactions either fail immediately or after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the TRACE API in 2.5 to track down what is happening near or around that time.  That should help get you more information as to what is happening. 
I use this for debugging http://upscene.com/products.misc.fbtm.php kinda buggy itself, but when it is working it is a god send.

Answer (score 0):

Are some Client-Connections going DOWN at 12:00 PM? I had a similar problem on a 70.000 records sized table:

Client "A" has a permanently open DB Connection like "select * from TABLE". This is a "read only transaction" but reason enough for the server to generate Record-Versions. Why?
Client "B" made massive Updates to this Table, the Server tries to preserve the world like it was when "A" startet her "select". This is normal for Transaction able DB-Servers, and its implemented by creating Record Copies of the record-data before its updated.
So in my case for this TABLE 170.000 Record Versions existed. You can measure this by

gstat -r -t TABLE db.fdb | grep versions

If Client "B" goes down, the count of Record-Versions is NOT growing any more. Client "A" is the guilty one, freezing all this versions, forces the server to hold it. Finally if Client "A" goes down (or for example a firewall rule cuts all pending connections) Firebird is happy to start the process of getting rid of the now useless Record-Versions. 
This "sweep"?! is bad programmed (even 2.5.2) cpu is 3% it do only <10.000 Versions / Minute so this TABLE has a performance of about 2%.